# Li-ion battery parallel connection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am getting confused how to use the Li-ion batteries for our requirement. Here are the details for it:

1. Initially, a user will have one Li-ion battery (3.7 V, 2000 mAh).
2. A user can increase the battery capacity to 8000 or 10000 mAh or some random value.
3. How should make the circuit? All Li-ion batteries connected in parallel? If I add one in parallel, the battery capacity will increase, but what should I consider to design in parallel?
4. An individual Li-ion battery has an individual BMS.
5. If a user wants to make as stackable, will stackable is nothing parallel connection?

Kindly let us know deeper points before designing.

Comment: Please simulate or calculate what will happen if the user installs a battery charger fully to 4.2 V in parallel with the existing battery, discharged currently to say 3.1 V.

Comment: *charged. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do not allow the user to do this. You have no control over the cell status.

Comment: @winny, what is combination to do achieve above situation? and if I use single charger IC - should I connect only one battery to it? I can't connect 2 batteries in parallel?

Comment: Please simulate or calculate it first so you understand the problem you have at hand. Soliciting for options are off-topic here but if you are stuck with a particular solution for your problem, we are happy to help.